# cyclic dependency using the p2-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I 've been using the p2-maven-plugin and I have some problems: it seems to be generating cycling dependencies but I could not find why (the same jars in maven show no problem). I am wondering whether anyone can help.

here is my **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001 XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.reficio.rcp</groupId>
<artifactId>example-p2-site</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
            <artifactId>p2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <!-- specify your depencies here -->
                            <!-- groupId:artifactId:version -->
                            <artifact><id>org.apache.shiro:shiro-aspectj:1.3.2</id></artifact>
                            <artifact><id>org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.3.2</id></artifact>
                            <artifact><id>org.apache.shiro:shiro-ehcache:1.3.2</id></artifact>
                            <artifact><id>net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.6.9</id></artifact>
                            <artifact><id>net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.9.0</id></artifact>
                            <artifact><id>commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1</id></artifact>
                            <artifact><id>org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1</id></artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>reficio</id>
        <url>http://repo.reficio.org/maven/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

here is the [cyclic dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0VTi.png) (*look for org.apache.shiro.core*)

Thanks in advance
K. Apostolou